# PHP timeout on fread() from a device (serial, dev/serial0)

Tags: php, serial-port

I have seen the question numerous times, but most of the time referring to website URLs. My hair ´s gone grey by now:

I am trying to read a serial port through a webserver. I open the device with $fp = fopen("/dev/serial0", "r+"), I can write to it (fwrite) and read from it (fread). However, if the serial device is not switched on, the response waits for input it will never receive. The php script called from the javascript client hangs indefinitely. When I subsequently switch the device on, I get partial data back and I have to reset the server or read it several times before it is in sync again. I need a timeout.

I tried several solutions, e.g. with stream_set_timeout($handle, $timeout), but that seems to only work with streams. If I add nonblocking too it will return empty, even if the device is on.

I than wrote a script that executes a shell command with a timeout (which works for other functions) and use (cat /dev/serial0). Alas the data I am getting is raw (as expected), but cat returns extra characters.

What could be the solution here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `stream_select` together with `fread` maybe? http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php

Comment: Serial communication is only as stateful as *the protocol that you implement* to communicate over it. If your client doesn't know whether or not it's connected, or when it should be finished reading data off the wire, then that's a problem with your protocol. In the general sense you should most likely be using non-blocking reads and/or `stream_select` as suggested by Marius.

Comment: stream_select did come up in my quest for answers, however, I am not very familiar with this kind of file/device handling (I´m old school). So I just open the serial device with fopen() and then stream_select will know which stream to select? It does not return the actual stream only the fact that it has changed? I´ll have a try in the mean time.....